# Is there a way to block drag&drop drops into a WKWebView in iOS 11?

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, wkwebview

If I have a contenteditable as part of my HTML loaded in my WKWebView, the webview seems to automatically accept drops of various types like images and text. Is there a way to stop that and only allow certain content types to drop?

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but have you looked at [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebviewconfiguration)?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in javascript

```
<script>
    function stopDrop(event) {
        // stop default action
        e.originalEvent.stopPropagation();
        e.originalEvent.preventDefault();

        // process dragged files
        var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files
        for (var f in files) {
            ...
        }
    }
</script>
<div ondrop="stopDrop(event)"></div>
```